# How to modify text in string with checkbox for React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I'm using MUI checkbox component

```
import React from 'react';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

export default function CheckboxLabels() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup row>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox checked={state.checkedA} onChange={handleChange} name="checkedA" />}
        label="highlight"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

I need find text in string with id = "passage"

How can I get this dom-node and add tag

```
<i className="selected-text">This text is selected</i> ?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to wrap parts of the text with the `<i>` tag. I'd say your best option is the following:

```
const originalText = 'This is a long paragraph but This text is selected in this long paragraph';
const textToHighlight = 'This text is selected';
const otherTextParts = originalText.split(textToHighlight);
console.log(otherTextParts);
// ["This is a long paragraph but ", " in this long paragraph"]

return (
<label>
  {otherTextParts.map((textPart, i) => (< key={textPart + i}>
  <span>{textPart}</span>
  {i < otherTextParts.length - 1 && (<i className="selected-text">{textToHighlight}</i>)}  
</>)}
</label>)
```

Comment: How to get dom node by id. Thrue createRef?